# When should Uint8 in Dart/Flutter be used?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I'm working on a flutter project with lots of bytes and byte arrays. I noticed that i had access to Uint8 and Uint8List. If i understand correctly, the Uint8List will save some memory over using a normal list with bytes. However, it seems that the Uint8List only accepts regular integers. Is there any usecase for using Uint8 type? Or should i be using the int type for bytes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the advantages of using Uint8List over List<int> when dealing with byte arrays in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897831/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-uint8list-over-listint-when-dealing-with-byte)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: The question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897831/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-uint8list-over-listint-when-dealing-with-byte)

According to the documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html), it accepts integers and then truncates those to the lower eight bits. This means you can effectively store four list entries in a standard 32 bit integer. When retrieving an integer, the integer is most likely prepended by the amount of bytes a reqular `int` uses.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the Uint8List, but what is the usecase of an Uint8? It seems like its only there as a marker.